# php date/mktime returning strange result

Tags: php, date

I got an array that contains the date for my currently displayed article archives and looks like this:

```
<?php    
// Code:
echo '<pre>'; print_r($date_result); echo '</pre>';
?>

// output:
Array
(
    [0] => 2008
    [1] => 03
    [2] => 11
)
```

Then I try to build the result to output a title for this archive page:

`$name = date( 'l', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $date[1], $date[2], $date[0] ) ); // works`

But when i try to make the same for month & years i always get one month/year before the given date:

```
// Month
$name = date( 'M', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $date[1], 0, 0, 0 ) ); // input: eg. (int) 03 - output 'February'

// Year
$name = date( 'Y', mktime( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, $date[0] ) ); // input: eg. (int) 2008 - output '2007'
```

I really can't get around it. What am I doing wrong with month & year dates? Thanks!

Comment: So what day of the month is 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From php.net:

> Example #3 Last day of next month
>
> The last day of any given month can be
>   expressed as the "0" day of the next
>   month, not the -1 day.

So 0 entered for day or month will be giving you the previous month or year.

Try putting

```
$name = date( 'M', mktime( 0, 0, 0, 1, $date[1], 1) );
```

Comment: Setting it to (int) 1 instead of zero was a perfect hint. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
$time = mktime( 0, 0, 0, $date[1], $date[2], $date[0] );
// Month
$month = date( 'M', $time ); // Outputs 'Mar' (March)
// Year
$year = date( 'Y', $time ); // Outputs '2008'
```